# Move/Merge non adjacent partitions with dual boot Windows 10 + Fedora 29

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, fedora, gparted

My partitions look like this:

- Gparted

[image]

- KDE partition manager

[image]

I want to expand `/dev/nvme0n1p7` with the unallocated space between Windows 10 partition and Fedora boot partition; unfortunately, I'm not sure how to solve the problem, even though, I have read a lot of *similar* questions.

*Note: The unallocated space is larger than the partition I want to expand*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic method that works with non-LVM partitions:

1. Boot from a live CD so that both partitions are unmounted.
2. Move the p6 "/boot" partition to the beginning of unallocated space.
3. Now the unallocated space becomes adjacent to p7 "fedora".
4. Move the p7 "fedora" partition to the beginning of unallocated space.
5. Now the unallocated space is to the right of p7 "fedora".
6. Expand the p7 "fedora" partition and its filesystem to the right.

However, this could probably be done fastest by creating a second LVM PV in that space, and letting LVM do the merging. (It won't look very neat in the partition table, but on the other hand, it can be done from the running OS and what's the point of having LVM if you don't use it for anything?)

Note: I have not tested this; it's based entirely on the manuals.

1. Create an empty partition to claim all the unallocated space.
2. Add the new partition to LVM using `pvcreate /dev/nvme####`.
3. Add the new partition to the main volume group using `vgextend fedora /dev/nvme####`.
4. Extend the Fedora logical volume using `lvresize --size +147G /dev/fedora/####`
5. Grow the filesystem using `resize2fs /dev/fedora####` or other apropriate tool.

Comment: **Thank you!** The second method works!